# Why does Pay Later button appear when using sandbox but not with production/live client id? (PayPal JavaScript SDK)

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal JavaScript SDK to create a Pay Later button. Everything works a treat when I test with the sandbox.

[Pay Later button shows using sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Sv2.png)

Here are the query parameters I'm using for the sandbox.

client-id=sb&components=buttons,messages&disable-funding=card,venmo&enable-funding=paylater

When I use the production/live client id the PayPal button appears but not the Pay Later button.

[Pay Later button does not show using production/live client id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfogI.png)

Here are the query parameters I'm using for production/live.

client-id=**[production/live client id here, removed for privacy]**&components=buttons,messages&disable-funding=card,venmo&enable-funding=paylater

I changed the client-id parameter from sb to the production/live client id.

I expected to see the Pay Later option when using production/live. I assumed that if sandbox worked, it would work on live.

The Pay Later button was a no show.

I realize the buttons are dynamic.

Any tips on what I can do to get the Pay Later button on production/live?

Answer (score 0):

What are your query string parameters for the PayPal `sdk/js` script in each case?

It could be as simple as adding `&enable-funding=paylater` in live, but there are other potential issues. The Pay Later button is generally only eligible for payers with an IP address that matches to the country that supports the currency, so for example

- if `&currency=USD` only buyers with a US IP will see Pay Later
- if `&currency=GBP` only buyers with a UK IP will see Pay Later
- if `&currency=EUR` only buyers with an IP address of one of the
  European countries that supports that Pay Later button will see it (I think Italy and Germany and possibly France IP buyers have it for example)

Another thing that will prevent Pay Later button eligibility is if it is a subscriptions or `&vault=true` integration.

Comment: I added the query parameters to my original post. I'm in the US.

Comment: If the same happens at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server with `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxx&components=buttons,messages&disable-funding=card,venmo&enable-funding=paylater"></script>` (substitute live client-id value) when testing from a US ip address, then the issue is the live account and either its business type or how it has transacted in the past. Contact PayPal for support.

Comment: I did as you suggested and the code did not work there so contacting PayPal is next. Thank you.